# How do you prevent Windows 8.1 from automatically disabling integrated graphics?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card

I have an Asus laptop running Windows 8.1, with Intel HD 4000 graphics on board, and an external GTX 960 attached through the mPcie slot on my computer.

Whenever I attempt to boot Windows with the eGPU attached, it automatically disables the Intel graphics, and makes the other card use its resources.

**So my question is, is there any way I can prevent Windows from disabling the integrated graphics?**

Any help or answer is appreciated!

Comment: Does your BIOS have an IGPU Multi Monitor setting? http://superuser.com/questions/860622/igpu-multi-monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason that you wouldn't want to use the GTX 960? I guess one thing you could do is go into the `device manager` and disable the GTX 960 driver. Then when you want to use it, you could enable it. It might not be the most ideal, but it's a method that should work.

Comment: That is a good method, but my end goal is to have both devices running at the same time. If Windows doesn't disable my Intel card, then it should move the GTX 960 into a memory space I have added just for the card, so I can then use both at the same time to achieve an Nvidia Optimus link.

Comment: @AeroStar ah I see. From my knowledge that capability is very limited, to specific motherboards. Plugging in an external card automatically disables IGP on almost all boards. There are a select few (desktop motherboard chipsets) that can apparently achieve this dual graphics processing. Why someone would want to do that? I have no idea. You can read more about it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)

Comment: Yes, I have yet to find out if my laptop can use Optimus, and I am still trying to, because if I can successfully implement it I can increase link speed. Also, as far as I know, Nvidia optimus depends on the model of the Integrated GPU and the eGPU, not the motherboard (Although I could be wrong). Anyways, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @AeroStar I think I have the answer to that. Nvidia Optimus is something they created, where your integrated graphics and dedicated graphics will switch automatically to help conserve battery life. Now here is the trick. Nvidia Optimus targets mobile PCs. So in order to utilize this technology, you have to have a laptop that has an Nvidia mobile series dedicated graphics, and the on-board graphics. So this is supported for their mobile series cards, like the GTX 960M, etc. In your case you have the eGPU which is a different implementation of having dedicated and on-board graphics.

Comment: @AeroStar So therefore I don't think you will be able to utilize this method. Here is a list of [Optimus Supported GPUs](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus/supported-gpus?field_gpu_type_value=All&page=1)

Comment: Yup, you are right. I have successfully initialized both cards with your method, but optimus hasn't engaged. But I appreciate the input!